# Android R namespacing with multiple apps

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I have 2 android apps. `appA` depends on module `assets`, `appB` depends on `moduleB`. `moduleB` also depends on `assets`.

I'm trying to make R namespacing and added gradle property for that:
`android.namespacedRClass=true`.

However after I build the project I see that `moduleB` can't access resources from `assets`.

This is the file structure:

```
.
├── appA
│   └─ build
│       └── generated
│           └── not_namespaced_r_class_sources
│               └── debug
│                   └── processDebugResources
│                       └── r
│                           └── my
│                               └── package
│                                   ├── R.java
│                                   ├── moduleB
│                                   │   └── feature
│                                   │       └── R.java
│                                   └── assets
│                                       └── R.java
├── AppB
│   │
│   └── ...
├── moduleB
│   └── intermediates
│       └── compile_only_not_namespaced_r_class_jar
│           └── debug
│               └── generateDebugRFile
│                   └── R.jar
└── assets
    └── src
        └── main
            └── res
                ├── color
                │   └── ...
                ├── drawable
                │   └── ...
                └── values
                    └── ...
```

R.jar doesn't contain needed resources. And `assets` R is in build for `appA` (I guess that's why `moduleB` can't access generated `R.java` for `assets`).

I've seen this approach at [SdkSearch](https://github.com/JakeWharton/SdkSearch) app, but it uses single app module. Is it possible to use such approach with 2 apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets as android project has manifest with pakage declaration. So I had to import `R` class from this package:

`<manifest package="my.package.assets" />`

```
import my.package.assets.R as AssetsR
...
val image = context.getDrawable(AssetsR.drawable.image)
```